# Deactivate Flows, Workflows, Validations using ANT

Tags: ant

Is there any way we can deactivate Workflows, Validation Rules, Visual Workflows, Process Builder using ANT Migration Tool

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, yes. In most cases it's as simple as changing the active attribute from true to false, but you'll want to read the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) for specifics.

For example (inside Lead.object):

```
<validationRules>
    <fullName>First_Name_Required</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <description>First Name Required</description>
    <errorConditionFormula>ISBLANK(FirstName)</errorConditionFormula>
    <errorMessage>This field is required.</errorMessage>
</validationRules>
```

Changing "true" to "false" will deactivate the rule. Just check the documentation for specifics.